# phpsec lib path is not working from cron job

Tags: php, cron, phpseclib

The file path for my script is

```
/var/www/html/MyProject/index.php
```

when I run the script as

`~/./Myproject$ php index.php` its runs perfectly

When I run the script as

```
~$ php /var/www/html/MyProject/index.php
```

It does not read the phpseclib file path

My index.php file is

```
<?php

include("crud.php");
include("functions.php");

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SFTP.php');

...

?>
```

error:

```
PHP Warning:  include(Net/SFTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/MyProject/index.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Net/SFTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear/phpseclib') in /var/www/html/MyProject/index.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Net_SFTP' not found in /var/www/html/MyProject/index.php on line 186
```

How to run the php script form cron job?

Comment: What errors do you see in the error log? I am pretty sure that your problem is that you're including files with relative paths (include("crud.php");) and when you run the script from a different folder it doesn't see the files you're including. The error log would have errors about not being able to find the includes if this really is the problem.

Comment: EDITED the question, crud and functions.php works fine and phpseclib is in /MyProject/ folder

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, you can see that `phpseclib` is not being added to the include path correctly. Try this for the set_include_path instead:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .  __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpspeclib');
```

The `__DIR__` will take into account the location of the file you're executing, rather than trying to find `phpspeclib` relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing phpseclib1.0.12  library to the **/usr/share/** or if you are running from the Project then you can try adding like this:

```
set_include_path('/var/www/html/phpseclib1.0.12');
include('Net/SFTP.php');
```